# Unattended-upgrades will secure all my programs?

Tags: linux, debian, security

I'm on debian 9

If I have set my apt to automatically update with unattended-upgrades (only security updates), will I have my softwares fixed automatically, or it's not enough?

Example with:

https://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_24.html#CVE-2019-0211

Apparently, I'm still on apache 2.4.25-3 and I suppose it's not fixed?

So I have a false sense of security with these automatic upgrades, or I don't understand something

Comment: Depends a bit on your distribution, but it's common to [backport important security fixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backporting). For this particular CVE in Debian, [2.4.25-3+deb9u6 is vulnerable; 2.4.25-3+deb9u7 is not](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2019-0211).

Comment: oh it's nice, so it means that normally it should work fine, now why am I on deb9u6 and not deb9u7?

Comment: You only installed security updates, and not all updates?

Comment: yes it's configured only for security updates Debian-Security

Comment: Ok it finally updated itself, but why am I late by several days?